# Laptop turns off after a few minutes of being unplugged

Tags: 16.04, power-management, shutdown, battery, touchscreen

I need help with an issue I've been having for the past month. I have an HP touchscreen laptop. I uninstalled Windows on it, and am running Ubuntu 16.04.

The laptop works perfectly fine while plugged in to a charger. However, when I unplug it, even for a few minutes, the laptop turns off. I have to restart it when it is plugged in, afterwards.

I looked online for some solutions, and found a solution that could be helpful (top post on http://ccm.net/forum/affich-198127-laptop-turns-off-when-power-cord-is-removed). However, the solution appears to be for windows HP computer/laptops only. Since I do not have windows anymore, I can not try this solution.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me find a solution to this issue.

Comment: Is you battery bad? Click the battery in the upper right hand corner and get the power statistics.

Comment: Is it shutting itself down because it thinks the battery is low, or just powering off like the power cord or battery was removed instantly? Can you turn it back on and **get into the bios**  (don't boot Ubuntu) for a few minutes without it shutting off?

Comment: yes I can get into the bios. I don't think the battery is bad, it is a fairly new laptop.

Comment: @Hat have you figured it out cause i'm having same problem with my laptop.

Comment: @ShanKhaliq Unfortunately not. I remember that I switched back to Windows, but I was still having the problem. I don't think the problem had anything to do with Ubuntu. Microcenter could not fix the problem either. I was able to return the laptop with a refund b/c I had a warranty. Good luck.

Comment: @Hat Thanks for update i'm a Linux user switching to windows is not an option for me. but I'll try to figure out if it's with the laptop hardware i think mine only go die when the battery is 100% and the charger is disconnected afterwards